# How to sendkeys to text box with Selenium on webpage with keyhandler

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, textbox, keystroke

I have a Selenium script in Python that was previously working with Firefox, but the website has installed a keyhandler on the text box, and it won't accept any input. On this line it will freeze, and be unable to complete the command. I tested it with regular keystrokes and it was the same result.

```
text_box.click()
text_box.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "a")
```

Is there a way to override this? I included the Javascript and HTML from the text box below.

```
function WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var target;
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        target = event.target;
    }
    else {
        target = event.srcElement;
    }
    if ((typeof(target) != "undefined") && (target != null)) {
        if (typeof(target.onchange) != "undefined") {
            target.onchange();
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

```
<input name="ctl00$cph1$d1$txtEndDate" value="09/02/2016" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cph1$d1$txtEndDate\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl00_cph1_d1_txtEndDate" textchanged="txtEndDate_TextChanged" style="width:86px;margin-left:30px;" type="text">
```

Comment: Have you tried focusing / clearing the input? 
Also you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936403/sendkeys-are-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I had a click command already, and adding clear after it didn't change anything. The JavascriptExecutor from your link might work, which I'm guessing is execute_script in Python. Not sure of the Javascript to execute though.

Comment: Well you didn't mention the click before. Also, I see a **if (event.keyCode == 13")** statement in the JS so other checks and onchange() triggers only after the 13 key code (Enter button pressing). So try sending keys and send an enter key in the end

Comment: Sorry, I added it now. I didn't think it was a problem as it was working. Adding the enter didn't work, but with the keyboard enter isn't needed, so maybe it's not this Javascript code that's the problem. There's a lot of other javascript code in the function after it, which has a lot of text.

Comment: Well, I don't know, the last option which I can suggest is trying to change the value of input directly like here: 
https://seleniumbyneeds.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/alternate-way-for-sendkeys/

Comment: You helped me solve the problem, thanks. The stale exception from the Javascript made me realise that something must've caused that. It turns out, the click needed to be removed, and send_keys worked again. Before it had to be there, otherwise send_keys wouldn't work.