# Ctrl + v (Paste) in string or in text file

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using selenium web driver, I want to copy html text from clip board and paste that in string or in any file.

Here is my code:

```
IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//[@id='textAreaforMarkup']"));
element1.Click();
element1.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");
String text = element1.Text;
Console.WriteLine("HTML Text:" + text );
```

But text is null. Is there any way to copy data from website and paste that in a file or in string.

Help will be highly appreciable. 
Thanks

Comment: "String or text file"? You're trying to paste it in an *element* by *simulating* a Ctrl+V keypress. Btw, if there is any other way to get that text, it would be better not to use the clipboard. You can also use SendKeys to send a piece of text to the element. You may want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936403/sendkeys-are-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: @golezTrol On web page there is button to copy html. when i press using selenium text store in Ctrl + c now issue is how can i paste that in string variable.

Comment: @golez is there any way to store sendkeys in string variable or in file. or any alternative way so i can perform operation on text.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Clipboard content by doing this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

Comment: @michel I'm copying data from text area it store in Ctrl + C and now i want paste it in String variable. 
and i tried this    string  text =  Clipboard.GetText(); not working.