# Selenium Code Skips TextBox and The script doesn't throw any error

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVExd.png)I am trying to write a script where I need to put phone and Name, in the textbox.
I am identifying the element using `xpath`.
But sometimes my scripts misses the phone number textbox and doesn't throw an error,whereas 'Caller Name' textbox it doesn't miss.Both the textbox are in same frame.
I am unable to fix this help would be appreciated.[enter image description here][2]

page source for phone number box:`<input data-ctl="[&quot;TextInput&quot;]" id="InteractionANI" maxlength="10" type="text" value="2342323455" name="$PD_Interaction_pa47757999396642430pz$pInteractionANI" class="leftJustifyStyle" minchars="10" data-change="[[&quot;refresh&quot;, [&quot;thisSection&quot;,&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&amp;=&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;,&quot;,&quot;:event&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;D_Interaction_pa47757999396642430pz&quot;]]]">`

my code:
`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='NickName']")).sendKeys("Test");
wait(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='InteractionANI']")).sendKeys("1234567892");

Comment: it would be better if you can share the code..

Comment: added the snippet of code

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendkeys are not working in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936403/sendkeys-are-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
element.click();
```

before

```
element.sendKeys();
```

Comment: Thanks....this worked but i tried writing a function...which worked tooo.......String str=driver.findElement(By.xpath("somexpath")).getAttribute("value");if(!str.equals("testdatafromexcel")){driver.findElement(By.xpath("somexpath")).sendkey("testdatafromexcel")}