# Python - send_keys entered into the inputs is lost in the next steps of the autotest

Tags: python, automation, pytest, sendkeys

I encountered a similar problem, that entering data into the fields, they are superimposed on the placeholder and after further test steps are simply erased from the inputs. https://prnt.sc/LurZD3vP2t0i https://prnt.sc/Jek5xcCWYgwY Tried everything described above

For example when using

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('manage_description').send_keys("TEST")
```

or `self.is_clickable('id', locator.element_id).send_keys('Test')` the item can't be found at all and gives a venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:89: TimeoutException

When using `self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id').value='Test'") "` the element is recalled, the information is entered, but it is not saved in the field and is erased in the next action Also used a combination with click

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ID').click()") self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ID').value='Test'")
```

But it did not yield any positive results either. If anyone has encountered a similar problem, please let me know

Comment: Have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936403/sendkeys-are-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @undetectedSelenium