# Selenium web scrape - WebDriverException after the first iteration of the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a Selenium web-scraping loop on Chrome using MacOS arm64, aiming to loop through a list of keywords as inputs to an input box, search for each one and get the text of an output attribute.
I have used the same code for a similar task a few months ago and it worked well, but now it can only finish the first iteration, then Chrome shuts down with WebDriverException Error.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://canvas.instructure.com/accounts/1?enrollment_term_id=235")

# Login to the website, code omitted here

search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#TextInput_2')))

instructor = []
fall_courses = pd.read_excel("spring 2024 courses.xlsx")
course_list = fall_courses["course_list"].tolist()
for course in course_list:
    search_box.send_keys(course)
    try:
        person_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,('//*[@id="content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/a/span'))))
        name = person_element.get_attribute('name')
        try:
            person_element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,('//*[@id="content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div[2]/a/span'))))
            name2 = person_element2.get_attribute('name')
            combined_names = name + ", " + name2
            instructor.append(combined_names)
            print(combined_names)
        except TimeoutException:
            instructor.append(name)
            print(name)
        time.sleep(1)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "a")
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

    except TimeoutException:
        print("course doesn't exist")
        time.sleep(1)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "a")
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

driver.quit()
```

It is able to successfully finish one iteration (input first keyword, retrieve attribute text, delete the keyword), but when it attempts to iterate again, it seems no longer being able to recognize or get `search_box` again, and Chrome shuts down so I get the WebDriverException error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.129)
```

What I have done:

1. I have checked that the path for `search_box` is the same all the time, with or without input. There's no other input box on this webpage with the same path.
2. I have confirmed that my Chrome and ChromeDriver's versions are the latest and compatible.
3. I have checked my laptop's CPU and memory, and also cleared Chrome's browsing cache.
4. I have confirmed that the for-loop works fine.

However, none of these helped. Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be the possible reasons of this situation? Is it due to any restrictions on the webpage? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried the code on my friend's laptop and it worked fine. Not sure why it wouldn't work on my laptop... Did I not clear my Chrome cache right(?)

Answer (score 0):

[Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25804316/18509670)

> I also had that problem, but then I made it work by:
>
> ```
> myInputElm.click();
> myInputElm.clear();
> myInputElm.sendKeys('myString');
> ```

Could be a problem with just that the search box is not selected/focused.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer! I just figured out it might still be my browser caching problem even though I've cleared cache already. My code works fine on my friend's laptop. But thanks again!